# hide and unhide half of a document, as in the exam documentclass

Tags: parallel-texts

The documentclass 'exam' allows to make two documents simultaneously: (1) one with just questions, and (2) one with both questions and answers.

I would want an idea of a similar sort. I am currently making two documents at the same time, one is an English document and the other is its translation into another language, say, Japanese.
So, it would be convenient if I can write everything in one tex file, and make three kinds of pdf files: (i) English part only, (ii) Japanese part only, (iii) both English and Japanese parts, the last being for the editorial purpose.

Examples are below. In other words, I want some part of a document to appear and disappear, depending on my needs. Is that possible?

PDF output (i):

[image]

PDF output (ii):

[image]

PDF output (iii):

[image]

Please don't worry about Japanese-language issues. You could teach me in case of English and French, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there are some advanced packages available, but you could achieve this with very basic methods. Consider a file `subfile.tex` with contents

```
\begin{English}
Some English text Some English text Some English text Some English text
Some English text Some English text Some English text Some English text
\end{English}

\begin{Japanese}
Some Japanese text Some Japanese text Some Japanese text Some Japanese text
Some Japanese text Some Japanese text Some Japanese text Some Japanese text
\end{Japanese}
```

and the master file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifShowJapanese\ShowJapanesetrue%\ShowJapanesefalse
\NewEnviron{Japanese}{\ifShowJapanese\BODY\fi}
\newif\ifShowEnglish\ShowEnglishtrue%\ShowEnglishfalse
\NewEnviron{English}{\ifShowEnglish\BODY\fi}
\begin{document}
\ShowJapanesefalse
\input{subfile.tex}

\ShowJapanesetrue\ShowEnglishfalse
\input{subfile.tex}

\ShowEnglishtrue
\input{subfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image]

As you can see, you can switch on and off English by setting `\ShowEnglishtrue` or `\ShowEnglishfalse`, respectively, and likewise for Japanese.

Comment: Thank you, @Schrödinger's cat! I would love simple solutions, and yours perfectly worked! When I run your master file, I should comment out two of the three pairs of lines in the end, am I right?

Comment: @JoeLee Yes, if you want only one of these options, you can comment out/remove the others (and set to true or false whatever you need in your application).